# how to keep only the rows greater than 10 in a cell array?

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I have a cell array of multiple rows and 2 columns and i want to keep only the rows that have in the second column value greater than 10?

Input:

```
'OR2V2' 16 
'RAB33B' 1
'ALDOC' 45
'CCNY' 8
'LIM2' 20 
'PECR' 29
```

Output:

```
'OR2V2' 16
'ALDOC' 45
'LIM2' 20
'PECR' 29
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Input = {'OR2V2' 16 ; 'RAB33B' 1 ; 'ALDOC' 45 ; 'CCNY' 8 ; 'LIM2' 20 ; 'PECR' 29};
Output = Input([Input{:,2}]>10,:);

%Output = 
%
%    'OR2V2'    [16]
%    'ALDOC'    [45]
%    'LIM2'     [20]
%    'PECR'     [29]
```

`[Input{:,2}]` gives the matrix containing elements of the second column of `Input`. You can also use `cell2mat(Input(:,2))` instead.  Then `[Input{:,2}]>10` gives the required logical indices of `Input` to use for the desired result.

Comment: is it possible to sort this cell array?

Comment: i have tried this command :sorted_matrix = sortrows(Output,2); but  want to sort them in desending order